# Awesome 90s psychedelic banner has gone

Tags: bug, status-completed

In Firefox 3.6.12 (Ubuntu 10.10 default), I no longer see any banner background at all on the main page. Other SEs still appear correctly; meta still appears correctly.

[image: Site with missing banner]

Comment: when did this start to happen?

Comment: Sometime within the last six hours, I think.

Comment: And just now (as in, between me checking before posting that comment, and posting this one), it is back.

Comment: Ah-ha, so it's not just me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of our build servers missed the image - I'll be researching this issue.

Comment: I call shenanigans! http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/323/psychedelic-90s-banner-style-header-has-got-to-go